# Laravel google images search

Tags: php, laravel

In my application users creating articles and adding images to it if user wont add a image, that application must search for it in google images. I'm googling it quite long but still can't find which tools do I need to achieve this.

**EDIT**
I tried Mimos approach but now something going wrong and now I get:

```
NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302:
Image source not readable
```

When i tried to save the image from url

ArticlesController store method:

```
 public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

            $file = Input::file('file');
            $imgTitle = $request->title;
            $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';
            $request->image_path = $imagePath;

            Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'image_path' => $imagePath));

            Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);
        } else {
//            $file = Input::file('file');
            $imgTitle = $request->title;

            $query = $imgTitle;

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=" . urlencode($query));

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

//            $file = file_get_contents($output);
            curl_close($ch);

            $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';

            $request->image_path = $imagePath;
            Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'image_path' => $imagePath));

            Image::make($output)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Unclear, off-topic (asking for external tools) and too broad. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before posting your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$query = 'Foobar';
$ch = curl_init(); 
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=".urlencode($query));

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string as json
$output = json_deocde(curl_exec($ch));

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
```

But I don't recommend to let a program decide what image it should take. You will maybe get a problem with copyright. Better set a default pic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it it's just exercise.